# Why does insulation facing go towards interior for exterior walls?

Tags: hvac, insulation

As I understand it, the paper facing is to stop the warm air on the inside of the house from going to the cold air outside of the house, thus preventing condensation.

But what about areas that have swapping temperatures. For example, in the winter the house is warmer than outside, so facing the barriers inwards stops the warm air from going out. But in the summer when it’s the reverse (and especially humid), the paper is facing inward so doesn’t that trap condensation between the siding and the walls? Or is this prevented somehow by the TyVek barriers I always see?

If it is related to the TyVek, isn’t it bad to have a vapor barrier on both sides of a frame? Or does TyVek prevent moister from entering one side but still allows it to dry out from the other like some poly-membranes?

Comment: does the paper has thermal properties ?

Comment: @Ruskes Um, no? It's a vapor retarder, like on insulation batts.

Comment: so the humidity is always higher outside then inside

Comment: Have you considered using unfaced insulation?

Comment: @Ruskes in the Spring/Summer in my state, humidity is more outside than inside (we have a great HVAC)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I was pretty sure you’re not supposed to use unfaced insulation for exterior walls.

Comment: @pstatix -- that's not true at all -- rockwool batts are *never* faced, and are A-OK for exterior walls, for instance.  Read the BSC link Steve posted (as well as other stuff on that site) for more info

Comment: Note that the main reason for this barrier is to prevent condensation.  Condensation happens when the temperature dips below the dew point of the air.

Answer (score 1):

Vapor barrier goes on the warm side - as a seasonal average.

If you cool more than you heat, it goes outside. If you heat more than you cool, it goes inside.

Tyvek and other housewraps are very specifically air barriers, **not** vapor barriers. They prevent bulk air movement and fluid water ingress while permitting vapor to pass through.

Using cellulose insulation (**not** fiberglass) with no barrier is a good option if your climate puts you in doubt, as it retards air movement and manages moisture. ([Manufacturer link](https://www.greenfiber.com/uploads/documents/Greenfiber-Vapor-Retarder-Bulletin_PM-6.3-385-Rev-A.pdf), no particular affiliation.)

Comment: So the direction of the barrier is dependent on which side is warmer on average in a year? So if I cool my house for 4 months but heat if for 8, barriers need to be inward?